# NoReverseMatch at... Django error

Tags: html, python, base-de-datos, django, backend

tengo un pequeño error al intentar modificar datos almacenados en Django Oracle, al intentar agregar el enlace que me lleva a la función y me modifica el usuario me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo mi código de...

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.index, name = "index"),
     path('galery', views.galery, name = "galery"),
     path('toregister', views.toregister, name = "toregister"),
     path('register', views.register, name = "register"),
     path('administration', views.administration, name = "administration"),
     path('editar/<int:id>', views.editar, name = "editar")
     ]
```

**views.py:**

```
def administration(request):
     #Administracion
     usuarios = Usuario.objects.all()
     datos = {
         'usuarios': usuarios
     }
     return render(request, 'store/administration.html', datos)

def editar(request, id):
     usuario = Usuario.objects.get(id = id)
     if request.method == 'GET':
         form = UsuarioForm(instance = usuario)
         contexto = {
         'form': form
         }
     return render(request, 'store/register.html', contexto)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Nombre del Usuario')
apellidos = models.CharField(max_length = 60, verbose_name = 'Apellidos del Usuario')
email = models.CharField(max_length = 50, verbose_name = 'Email del Usuario')
rut = models.CharField(max_length = 10, primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Rut del Usuario', unique = True)
contraseña = models.CharField(max_length = 15, verbose_name = 'Contraseña del Usuario')

def __str__(self):
    return self.rut
```

**administration.html:**

```
<tbody>
        {% for users in usuarios %}
        <tr>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.nombre}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.apellidos}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.rut}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4">{{users.email}}</td>
            <td class="px-8 py-4"><a href="{% url 'editar/' users.id %}" class="p-2">Editar</a><br><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Es mi primera vez posteando aquí, cualquier otro código que necesiten o información me pueden avisar y se los mando. También si publiqué algo mal o no de la manera o formato correcto, es bienvenido cualquier comentario.

Comment: `a href="{% url 'namespace_de_tu_app:editar' users.id %}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra en como estas incluyendo la url en el template administration.html

Puedes colocarlo de esta manera si solo indicas el name de la url:

```
<td class="px-8 py-4"><a href="{% url 'editar' users.id %}" class="p-2">Editar</a><br><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
```

o de esta manera si indicaste un namespace al incluir tus urls y teniendo un name para la url:

```
<td class="px-8 py-4"><a href="{% url 'minamespace:editar' users.id %}" class="p-2">Editar</a><br><a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
```